# Apache Spark: Garbage Collection Logs for Driver

Tags: java, apache-spark, garbage-collection, google-cloud-dataproc

My Spark driver runs out of memory after running for about 10 hours with the error `Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-17" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. To further debug, I enabled G1GC mode and also the GC logs option using `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:+UseG1GC  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp`
 but it looks like it is not taking effect on the driver.

The job got stuck again on the driver after 10 hours and I dont see any GC logs under stdout on the driver node under `/var/log/hadoop-yar/userlogs/[application-id]/[container-id]/stdout` - so not sure where else to look. According to [Spark GC tuning docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning), it looks like these settings only happen on worker nodes (which I can see in this case as well as workers have GC logs in stdout after I had used the same configs under `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`). Is there anyway to enable/acquire GC logs from the driver? Under Spark UI -> Environment, I see these options are listed under `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` which is why I assumed it would be working.

**Environment:**
The cluster is running on Google Dataproc and I use `/usr/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster ...` from the master to submit jobs.

**EDIT**
Setting the same options for the driver during the `spark-submit` command works and I am able to see the GC logs on stdout for the driver. Just that setting the options via SparkConf programmatically does not seem to take effect for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

I believe `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` is handled by `SparkSubmit.scala`, and needs to be passed at invocation. To do that with Dataproc you can add that to [the properties field](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs#sparkjob) (`--properties` in `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark`).

Also instead of `-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties` you can use [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/driver-output#configuring_logging) to configure detailed logging.

I could see GC driver logs with:
`gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster CLUSTER_NAME --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --jars file:///usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar  --driver-log-levels ROOT=DEBUG --properties=spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:+UseG1GC  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp" --`

You probably don't need `--driver-log-levels ROOT=DEBUG`, but can copy in your logging config from `log4j.properties`. If you really want to use `log4j.properties`, you can probably use `--files log4j.properties`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The way we have setup our jobs, we reuse the same JAR to submit multiple runs with different properties which are part of the resources in the JAR itself. So, using spark-submit helps since we push the JAR once and reuse it multiple times. Also, we have had a few random issues with gcloud submit which is why we started using spark-submit (we had internal Google cases which were of not much use).

Comment: Your suggestion on it being part of the submit flow explains why it works with spark-submit - so I guess that resolves the problem here. Thanks for the help